# CSRC и SSRC в RTP

Tags: c++, аудио, видео, ffmpeg, rtp

Реализую протокол RTP, не могу разобраться с [RTP Payload Format for H.264 Video](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) а если точнее быть то с первыми 4 байтами в CSRC. Точного описания в гугле не найдено , может кто нибудь может хоть как то объяснить как это должно работать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775531/csrc-and-ssrc-in-rtp "To be honest, I have never seen anyone actually use SSRC or CSRC in any meaningful way. In all the code I've dealt with, we just generate a random number in SSRC and don't never bother filling in CSRC."

Answer (score 0):

Я тут копнул еще рфц-3550 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550)

SSRC: 32 bits
The SSRC field identifies the synchronization source.  This
identifier SHOULD be chosen randomly, with the intent that no two
synchronization sources within the same RTP session will have the
same SSRC identifier.  An example algorithm for generating a
random identifier is presented in Appendix A.6.  Although the
probability of multiple sources choosing the same identifier is
low, all RTP implementations must be prepared to detect and
resolve collisions.  Section 8 describes the probability of
collision along with a mechanism for resolving collisions and
detecting RTP-level forwarding loops based on the uniqueness of
the SSRC identifier.  If a source changes its source transport
address, it must also choose a new SSRC identifier to avoid being
interpreted as a looped source (see Section 8.2).

CSRC list: 0 to 15 items, 32 bits each
The CSRC list identifies the contributing sources for the payload
contained in this packet.  The number of identifiers is given by
the CC field.  If there are more than 15 contributing sources,
only 15 can be identified.  CSRC identifiers are inserted by
mixers (see Section 7.1), using the SSRC identifiers of
contributing sources.  For example, for audio packets the SSRC
identifiers of all sources that were mixed together to create a
packet are listed, allowing correct talker indication at the
receiver.

Извиняйте, что ответом, в комент не влезло)

Comment: как формируется csrc вроде как понятно все кроме 4 байт. Я тоже находил все что вы скинули но вот где именно взять что лежит вначале пакета и как эти значения получить совсем не представляю

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев, я не совсем понимаю вопрос, вам непонятны именно 4 байта поля csrs (потому что это поле всего 4 байта) или первые 4 байта заголовка пакета РТП?

Comment: @АнтонИгнатьев, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol#Packet_header вот заголовок пакета, что именно у вас вызывает вопросы?)

Comment: CSRC identifiers, если посмотреть сформированный пакет то там все понятно кроме 4 первых байт. Сейчас постараюсь найти готовый пакет и скинуть его хекс